# Check current url of webpage using requests python 3.7.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

so I want to check if the current URL is example.com (example) then if it is then use if to do something like this: if current URL == example.com: then print something, but my problem isn't that it's that I don't know how to get current URL using requests with python 3. I have written code , but it's irrelevant to what I'm asking as there's no errors in my code so far. So my question is how to get current URL using requests with Python 3, any help is great.. thanks! I have looked everywhere and can't find anything on it.

Comment: could you paste a part of the code (at least the part where you sent the requests)

Comment: Current URL is exactly the same as you used in request

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is property called `.url`

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'https://www.amazon.com/'
>>> response = requests.get(url)
>>> response.url
u'https://www.amazon.com/'
```

Comment: But how to get the full raw URL when the `requests` call has headers, data, parameters, etc?  Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Getting the URL of your response is very simple:

```
r = requests.get("www.example.com")
print(r.url)
```